# react-native & ios: How to launch View controller from native module manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, uiviewcontroller

I want to launch `UIViewController` from native module manager.

From react-native: `MyNativeModuleManager.viewStreet()`

Is this the right way? using `DispatchQueue.main.async {` to launch UI ViewController.
Most of the times code works but sometimes react-native fails to launch UI View Controller.

I want back button too and hence I am using `UINavigationController`

```
//MyNativeModuleManager.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyNativeModuleManager, RCTEventEmitter)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(viewStreet)
@end

//MyNativeModuleManager.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(MyNativeModuleManager)
class MyNativeModuleManager: RCTEventEmitter {
  @objc
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return false
  }
  
  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    return []
  }
  
  @objc
  func viewStreet() -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      let topController = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController()
      let vc: UIViewController;
      vc = ViewStreetUIViewController()
      let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
      navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
      _ = vc.view
      UIView.transition(with: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!, duration: 0.65,options: [], animations: {
        topController?.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

&

```
//UIApplicationExt.swift
import Foundation

extension UIApplication {
  func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var topViewController: UIViewController? = nil
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
      for scene in connectedScenes {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
          for window in windowScene.windows {
            if window.isKeyWindow {
              topViewController = window.rootViewController
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      topViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }
    while true {
      if let presented = topViewController?.presentedViewController {
        topViewController = presented
      } else if let navController = topViewController as? UINavigationController {
        topViewController = navController.topViewController
      } else if let tabBarController = topViewController as? UITabBarController {
        topViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
      } else {
        // Handle any other third party container in `else if` if required
        break
      }
    }
    return topViewController
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found ?